# Mono timeout does not return the response on RestController after timeout but waits for the whole execution

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a rest controller as below.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

@RestController
public class DummyController {

@GetMapping("/get/mono")
public Mono<String> getTest(Integer groupId) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(10000); //Simulating a long running database call. 
        return "Success";
    }).timeout(Duration.ofMillis(50), Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("timed out");
        return "timeout";
    })).onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just(e.getMessage()));
}

}
```

Here, I expect the controller to return the response after the timeout of 50ms. But instead, the controller returns the timeout fallback response("timeout") after the execution time of 10000 ms.

The strange thing here is that, after the timeout of 50ms the code inside the timeout fallback gets executed. But it still waits for the Thread.sleep to complete before returning the response.

Is there anyway to make the controller return the response immediately after the timeout and not wait for the whole execution of the callable method.

A minimal reproducable version of the code is here: https://github.com/rahulgul8/MonoTimeout.git Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thread is blocked on the Thread.sleep() or any long running task. In this case, delegate the task to a different thread to execute the long running task and the main thread takes care of the timeout.

To do this, add subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()) to the Mono. This executes the task on the thread provided by the Schedulers.boundedElastic() keeping the main thread available to process the timeout.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

@RestController
public class DummyController {

@GetMapping("/get/mono")
public Mono<String> getTest(Integer groupId) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(10000); //Simulating a long running database call. 
        return "Success";
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()) //Add this to fix the issue.
      .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(50), Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("timed out");
        return "timeout";
    })).onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just(e.getMessage()));
}

}
```